# (MatLab) patternCustom 3D radiation plot not showing up

Tags: matlab

I am working on an antenna array working within wifi spectrum (2.4 GHz to 2.4835 GHz) for a university project, and as a part of that I have gotten it tested in a MVG SG24 with a frequency sweep from 2.4 GHz to 2.5 GHz. I have extracted the azimuth, elevation, frequency, theta, phi, magnitude data amongst others into a CSV file and try to use the patternCustom function in MatLab to represent this data.

The problem I am having is that, while the code compiles and does not seem to have any issues with the data provided, the actual radiation pattern does not show up on the plot, instead it is just empty.

I was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem before, and if so how/if they fixed it. I have attached the CSV file I am using, alongside the code I am running and a screen grab of the plot alongside one of how it is supposed to look. Any help is appreciated.

[Link to the CSV file that I am using.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MfXjW1JgfWpbZ5ppPZ_7I6iLbeLa421o/view?usp=sharing)

```
opts = detectImportOptions("Antenna Array Spherical data_Polar H_Polar V_Polar Θ_Polar Ф_E Total.csv");
opts.DataLines = 3;
opts.VariableNamesLine = 2;
patchData = readmatrix("Antenna Array Spherical data_Polar H_Polar V_Polar Θ_Polar Ф_E Total.csv",opts)

realTheta= patchData(:,8)
realPhi = patchData(:,10)
magnitudeE = patchData(:,12)

patternCustom(magnitudeE,realTheta,realPhi)
```

Image of how it is supposed to look.
[Taken from MatLab's article on the patternCustom function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beT80.png)

Image of how mine looks.
[Screen grab of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAqzR.png)

Comment: Shouldn’t this question be better suited on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @SohamSaha was a bit of coin toss to be honest, noticed there was a decent amount of MatLab questions here on the Math SE, so thought it might be worth a shot.

Comment: If you’d want my opinion, I think you should [migrate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318460/how-to-move-a-question-to-another-site) it

Comment: @SohamSaha I already heeded your advice, and just created a separate post on SO. Also, thanks for the input.  : )

Comment: You’re welcome!